# Get Process ID after starting psexec

Tags: powershell, pid

I have a script that calls notepad on a remote computer with psexec. Is there a way I can get the Process ID after it is started?

Here is what I have:

```
$PCname = "MyPC"
$SessionID = "2"
$Program = "Notepad.exe"
$FilePath = "C:\temp\"
$FileName =  "Test.txt"

set-alias psexec "C:\PsExec\psexec.exe"
   &psexec -s -d -i $SessionID \\$PCname $Program $FilePath\$FileName
```

After running I get this in the output window that shows the Process ID:

```
Connecting to MyPC...Starting PSEXESVC service on MyPC...Connecting 
with PsExec service on MyPC...Starting Notepad.exe on MyPC...
Notepad.exe started on MyPC with process ID 8352.
```

How can I grab the process ID?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Select-String` cmdlet to grab the process ID using a *regex*:

```
&psexec -s -d -i $SessionID \\$PCname $Program $FilePath\$FileName |
   Select-String 'process ID (\d+)' | 
   ForEach-Object {$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value}
```

Comment: I am a bit of a novice. How do I get my process ID from this?

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = (gps -ComputerName PcName| where{ $_.ProcessName -eq "Notepad.exe"} | select Id)
```

`$a.Id` contains the wanted Id

Comment: This works well if the only Notepad running on the machine is the one I started.